# MultiSystem won't recognize my USB

Tags: partitioning, windows, kubuntu, live-usb, multisystem

I have been suffering for all the night trying to get a live Windows USB for installing it in a double boot along my Kubuntu, however, it's just pointless waste of time as I have achieved nothing. I just plugged my USB(which had live Kubuntu on it) and opened MultiSystem to replace it with live Windows. The USB didn't show up. Than I tried formating USB. After a few years of research I found that I should mount my USB at `/media/MULTISYSTEM`. I did so. Than it shown up, but a foregin language error popped up(`Erreur: MultiSystem n'accepte pas les espaces dans les label de disques.`). What should I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google translate says it's french for "Error: MultiSystem does not accept spaces in disk labels".

So reformat again with a different name without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

**If someone gets [ERROR:
Disconnect/reconnect your USB drive as the mount point does not match the label!**]*

Not for everyones resolve, but for my Ubuntu-14.04.5 - I had to remove a USB-mount application. Mine in particular was **usbmount(0.022)** from the 'Ubuntu Software Center.'
Then the next step is to check `/etc/fstab` for anything like:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/A524-1B97 /mnt/A524-1B97 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=MULTISYSTEM 0 0
```

A524-1B97 was my USB stick

Remark it [#] out **or** better *just cut it!* as you don't need it anyway unless it is a permanent USB placement! 

I believe what was going on was the USB helper program was modifying the "fstab" file?

The final step is two parts:
 The first part is to cerate a folder/directory with permissions 755 `rwxr-xr-x` called 'MULTISYSTEM' (without quotes and all caps) in your `/media`in folder/directory.

Suggested was it's properties to: owner - root, group - root, However I skipped/forgot this and mine was set to 'James' and seem to work anyway perhaps as I have 'admin' rights?

The last part was to also make sure the USB stick was Labeled 'MULTISYSTEM'(without quotes and all caps) also, so there is a match or you will get an error from the *Mustisystem* application.  I had to open Gparted or Disks and unmont to relabel the USB stick

*Source 'Comments' from  **Martina Neumayer** • 2 years ago - [Linux Magazine](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Blogs/Productivity-Sauce/Create-a-Multi-boot-USB-Stick-with-MultiSystem)

**One final note:** it is best to format your USB in windows as FAT32 as *gParted* seems to confuse ownership and FAT32 should not have anything like that!!! 

If you don't have windows you can run Mini-windows found on "Hiren's Boot-CD" or other places.

Hope this Helps someone! James Niland